# Jade: each val in times returns "no such function: val"

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, pug

I have the following Jade:

```
template(name='hello')
    button(class="ui grey basic button", id="clickme")
        i(class="sun icon")
        | Times
    div(class="ui list")
        each val in times
            div.item= val
```

Where times is a session variable being called from a JS helper method.

I'm running a Meteor server, using Semantic-UI as my design framework.
When I try to use this Jade, the page inspector console (in Chrome) returns

```
Uncaught Error: No such function: val
```

I'm not sure what to fix, as I'm following the Jade (and Meteor-Jade) documentation to the letter.

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide your js code?

Comment: The error seems to suggest that the val function isn't scoped so that it can be read. The JS code would certainly be useful in seeing where/what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

`each` doesn't work with `in`. Try:

**Jade:**

```
div(class="ui list")
  each times
    div.item= val
```

**Js:**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Session.set('times', [{val: 'value1'}, {val: 'value2'}]);

  Template.hello.helpers({
    times: function () {
      return Session.get('times');
    }
  });
}
```

---

Or if you have an array instead of object in your Session variable, you can use `this`:

**Jade:**

```
div(class="ui list")
  each times
    div.item= this
```

**Js:**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Session.set('times', ['value1', 'value2']);
  ...
}
```